# YouTube Permanent Private Live Stream Link

Tags: streaming, youtube

Is it possible to create a permanent live stream link in youtube? I am working with a school and they would like their videos to be private, but we do not want to have to update the link every time there is a new live stream.

Another thing I thought about is if there was a way to automatically update a link on the school webpage that would show the live stream whenever it started? Maybe the YouTube API has the ability to update the link that changes every time a live stream starts?

If anyone has any suggestions on what we can do to keep the videos private but also have some type of persistent link to the live stream, it would be greatly appreciated. I am not worried about something being too technical as I am part of the school technology team.

Comment: there's probably a neater way to do it than that,

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Stream Now](http://youtube.com/live_dashboard) instead of Events, you'll have a permanent link to it at youtube.com/channel/`{ChannelID}`/live.

Your ChannelID is listed at https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced.

Comment: This is true if you are on Public. We are trying keep our account and stream on Private though

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer no longer works, instead use: https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=CHANNELID